# How to calibrate a mouse on 22.04

Tags: mouse, 22.04

I upgrade my Ubuntu from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS. To use my mouse is hard, because I have to click about 30 mm to the right, from where the click is needed. And this is not always possible, which makes it hard to f.e. close a window.

How the mouse can be calibrated? With my strong preference in the GUI. I have looked into the settings, but the mouse can not be calibrated there.

Answer (score 1):

I found in an old documentation, which comes very precise:

In Ubuntu 22.04 the buttons are no rectangle, but have rounded corners. Go with the mouse to the left top, near the button "activities". Because the button has rounded corners, it is possible to click in the very small area between the left top of the screen, and the activities button. Doing so calibrate the mouse to that point.

Very simple. Sorry, for asking. I had to do more research in advanced.